# Executar função de uma pagina em outra

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, google-maps

Estou com uma dúvida referente ao meu projeto. Tenho um botão em uma **página "x"** que ao clicar ele verifica a geolocalização no Google maps (preenche os inputs com as coordenadas). Até aí tudo bem, Preciso fazer essa função também em uma **página "y"** com o mesmo esquema: botão; ao clicar pego o value de dois campos inputs e então marca no mapa. Só que o mapa está na **pagina "x"** e o botão na **página "y"** e o script no mapa no "script.js".

Não estou conseguindo pensar alguma maneira em fazer isso, pois não tenho um conhecimento muito grande. Vi que as possibilidades em um AJAX da vida dariam certo, mas não tenho muito conhecimento.

Para ajudar, segue imagens:
[image: index.php]
[image: equipamentos.php]

Queria a ajuda de vocês quanto a essa dúvida, se há como fazer e um exemplo de como fazer isso.

Resumidamente, seria: executar botão na página y -> a função é lida de uma function no arquivo script. js onde está o mapa e as funções -> então executa essa função na página x e marca no google maps api a localização.

Comment: Essa página está a onde. Explique mais sobre onde as páginas estão.

Comment: Assim, tem a index.php onde está carregado o mapa (vindo do . js) os inputs e o botão de localizar. Quando preenche os inputs e aperta "localizar" o google maps posiciona um marcador na api de acordo com os valores do input. Até ai, ok, só que preciso fazer isso na pagina equipamentos.php onde eu referencio o mesmo arquivo . js com o mesmo botão e mesmo referenciando, ele não recebe os valores da function, muito menos marca na index.php a localização.

Comment: Coloquei imagens para melhorar o entendimento.

Comment: Bem. cambiar informações entre páginas é um tanto que complicado. Mas é possível. Só ainda não me vi fazendo isso. Uma solução mediana para esse problema seria renderizar esse crud em um modal e não em um poup-up. Com o modal você estará no mesmo documento podendo cambiar qualquer ação ou variável com javascript.

Comment: Entendi, o problema é que só deixei popup porque o mapa contém marcadores com js de window.open baseado nas informações no banco de dados.. Teria de ser mesmo em popup e tentar achar uma maneira de duas páginas trocarem informações

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/Window.localStorage) para salvar as coordenadas e na próxima página obtê-las. 
LocalStorage é um espaço para armazenamento no navegador do usuário.

Ex:

```
// Salva na página anterior
localStorage.setItem("latitude", "-450.56464984");
localStorage.setItem("longitude", "-38.89748914");

// Recupera na próxima página
document.getElementById("campo-latitude").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("latitude");
document.getElementById("campo-longitude").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("longitude");
```

Comment: Seria uma boa mesmo, mas não tem importância na ordem de abertura das páginas? Pois o equipamento.php abre depois do index.php? E no caso no valor da coordenada, vem de uma query do banco, no caso por exemplo: $row['latitude'], no caso:
localStorage.setItem("latitude", "latMap") -> (que é o ID do input hidden que guarda as coordenadas do banco)

Comment: Acredito que o dominio todo tenha acesso a mesmo localStorage.

Comment: E como consigo mandar isso para o campo input lá da index.php com o click do botão na página equipamentos.php? Desculpe a pergunta meio obvia, mas não sou muito bom com javascript mesmo.

Comment: Assim, na solução que eu dei, você salva ela no browser do usuário e fim, você pode recuperar esse valor em qualquer página. E você não passaria o ID pro localStorage.setItem(), você salva o valor do campo numa variável, e depois coloca essa variável no setItem(), assim: var coordenada = document.getElementById("latMap").val(); localStorage.getItem('latitude', coordenada);

Comment: Não sei se fiz algo errado mas, aparece no console que a function mandaCoordenada() is not defined.
Segue as linhas que fiz:

Na index.php coloquei :document.getElementById('latMap').innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('latitude', latitude);
        document.getElementById('lngMap').innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('longitude', longitude);

Comment: No equipamentos.php coloquei: function mandaCoordenadas(){
                            var latitude = document.getElementById('latMap').val();
                            var longitude = document.getElementById('lngMap').val();

                            window.localStorage.setItem('latitude', latitude);
                            window.localStorage.setItem('longitude', longitude);
                          });

Comment: Esse são os inputs do equipamentos.php:
<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"latMap\" id=\"latMap\" value ='". $row['lat'] ."'>
                          <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"lngMap\" id=\"lngMap\" value ='". $row['lng'] ."'>

Comment: O botão do equipamentos.php: <button id=\"submit\" onclick=\"mandaCoordenadas();\" class=\"btn btn-sm btn-primary\">
                                <i class=\"fas fa-map-marker-alt\"></i></button>

Comment: E o trecho do script.js :
function geocodeLatLng(geocoder, map, infowindow) {
      var input1 = document.getElementById('latMap').value;
      var input2 = document.getElementById('lngMap').value;
      var latlng = {lat: parseFloat(input1), lng: parseFloat(input2)};
      geocoder.geocode({'location': latlng}, function(results, status) {
        if (status === 'OK') {
          if (results[1]) {
            map.setZoom(19);
            map.setCenter(latlng);

Comment: var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map,
            url: 'index.php',
            icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png'
          });

          infowindow.setContent('Marcador temporário');
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        } else {
          window.alert('Nenhum resultado foi encontrado');
        }
      } else {
        window.alert('Geolocalização falhou devido a: ' + status);
      }
        marker.addListener("dblclick", function(){
        marker.setMap(null);
      });
    });
}

Comment: Vi no seu comentário lá em cima que você está usando window.open, desse modo é melhor passar os parametros pela URL, ex: windows.open("http://localhost/equipamentos.php?latitude=" + latitude +"&longitude=" + longitude); para pegar os dados você usa $_GET['longitude'] direto na página PHP, ou no JavaScript assim: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448545/how-to-retrieve-get-parameters-from-javascript

Comment: Certo, mas eu conseguiria mudar toda hora essa variável no link? Pois teria que clicar no botão e apresentar a variavel de cada equipamento caso o usuário queira ver onde está um por um no mapa

Comment: É possivel mudar toda hora sim

Comment: Entendi, mas isso não precisar ser no index.php? porque do mesmo jeito preciso que o botão do equipamentos.php mande isso para o index.php (nos campos input) e nem precisa pesquisar automatica, só mandando isso pros campos input ja me ajuda muito.

Comment: Sim, pode ser de qualquer lugar pra qualquer lugar

Comment: Entendi, só preciso saber como passar parametros para a url de forma dinâmica para fazer isso funcionar.. Já fez isso alguma vez ou já viu algo do tipo em algum lugar para me aconselhar?

Comment: windows.open("localhost/equipamentos.php?latitude=" + latitude +"&longitude=" + longitude); <<< assim está dinâmico, ta concatenando a URL com as variáveis.

Comment: onde tá escrito latitude e longitude, são variaveis